# Can a sum of a nonprincipal ultrafilter and a principal ultrafilter be equal to the nonprincipal ultrafilter?

Tags: logic, set-theory

If $ \mathcal U$ is a  nonprincipal ultrafilter and $\mathcal V$ is a principal ultrafilter, can $ \mathcal U \oplus \mathcal V$ be equal to $\mathcal U$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a context, I'll assume the question is about ultrafilters on arbitrary semigroups.  Then the answer is yes. Just take a semigroup that has an identity element $e$ (i.e., a monoid, for example a group) and let $\mathcal V$ be the principal ultrafilter that contains $\{e\}$.

Comment: More generally, if $\mathcal V$ contains $\{a\}$, then $\mathcal U\oplus\mathcal V=\mathcal U$ if and only if $\mathcal U$ contains the set $\{x:x\oplus a=x\}$.